# MYSQL - Check from Select "itself" possible?

Tags: mysql, select, xampp

I just started with mysql and I don't know if the way to make that check is the correct or I am going in the wrong direction.

I have a varchar named user_num in a table. and I need to check that when I do INSERT, the value of user_num_list have to be between [1, n] being "n" the quantiti of Objects that have the same Group has new Object.

I'm not English speaking and I'm sure it's a bit hard to understand, and for me to express myself, so there is some code:

```
create table player(
group varchar(15),
user_num int(15),
CONSTRAINT ck_player_user CHECK( user_num > 0 AND user_num < SELECT count(*) FROM player WHERE player.group=group)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I don't know if i can "SELECT" inside a CHECK statement and also i dont know how to express "player.group=group" meaning that group(new INSERT player_group) have to be same has player.group

Thank you.

Comment: So `user_num` for the first player in the group should be `< 0`?

Comment: user_num <= grup count. But thats not the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are out of luck.

First of all, MySQL does not validate the CHECK constraints before version 8.0.16. If you are using a MySQL version older than this one, MySQL will record the CHECK constraint and will **silently ignore it**
.

Second, in order to enforce this contraint you would need to use a subquery in it, and MySQL does not allow subqueries as part of the `CHECK` constraint. See [13.1.20.7 CHECK Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) where it literally says:

> - Subqueries are not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with subqueries in the CHECK condition is that it's practically impossible to implement. Consider what happens when you delete a row in this table. The count for the corresponding group will decrease, which might violate a CHECK constraint for another row. The system would need to reevaluate the checks for every row. If you now have one million rows in the table, one million queries need to be executed every time you INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE a row. If you would also permit cross table statements, all checks in the database need to be reevaluated on any change of data.

In theorie it would be possible to generate a "reverse check". The system would need to determine, which operations can possibly violate a check. In your case that would be deleting a row or updating a group. The "reverse check" could be

```
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM player p
    WHERE p.group = OLD.group
      AND p.user_num > (SELECT COUNT(*) from player p WHERE p.group = OLD.group)
)
```

I think you would agree, that it would be hard to implement a system, that is able to generate a reverse check like this. Queries can be much more complicated than yours. And for some queries there might not even exist a reverse check. If you look at how long it has taken to [implement the CHECK constraint](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464) - I wouldn't expect any subqueries to be permitted in the next decade.

So I would say - Your options are:

- Implement your checks in triggers
- Implement your checks in application code
- Change the requirements

I'd prefer the last one.